# The world's first quantum integrated circuit at the atomic scale - How does this advance quantum computing as a whole?

Tags: experimental-realization, architecture

I have a hobbyist/enthusiast understanding of Quantum Computing, having read a few books on the subject. I came across this new article and referenced Nature paper. I know a goal of quantum computing is to have a fault tolerant quantum computer. But I don't understand how an integrated circuit gets us closer to that goal. Could someone help me bridge the gap of how this discovery ties into the bigger picture of quantum computing?

https://phys.org/news/2022-06-scientists-quantum-processor-emulate-small.html

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-022-04706-0.pdf